# How to safely style when using Zurb Foundation for your website?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm new to foundation, and using the latest version. I would like to add various kinds of styling to my pages, e.g. make some or all input boxes rounder or thicker, apply specific colors to specific elements (and of course, choose between custom color pallets that come along with Zurb if any, to begin with).

Should I use plain styles of my own? or should I use existing foundation classes? Is there also a collection of built-in color pallet or style themes to choose from?

I should say I'm not sure whether I have to use/download the Sass version for any of that, as it is left rather ambiguous [on the download page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) to me, whether Sass/SCSS is a separate version or download of Foundation.

Of course I can role my own styles, but I'd like to learn whether there's a cleaner or more productive approach.

Comment: If you don't know sass, use the regular css files. If you want to change things, create a separate css file and override the css rules. As long as you reference the css file with the overridden rules after the main css file, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. And if I know sass? btw this can be posted as an answer :)

Comment: So it's all done by looking at the CSS and overriding it, for this framework? it's a bit dodgy guessing all the cases where a given css rule is used by the framework, before brutally overriding it. Is there a more deterministic way to go?

Comment: You can download a custom build, but I've always used the complete package and overridden as and when I needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know sass, use the regular css files. If you want to change things, create a separate css file and override the css rules. As long as you reference the css file with the overridden rules after the main css file, you should be good to go.

If you do know Sass, just edit the Sass file and when you're done, compile it to CSS using any number of tools available (Google "Sass to Css").

Whenever I've worked with Foundation, I've downloaded the whole job lot, but you can download a custom build from [Here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation).